# API Get Request to pull data from an online database

Tags: ruby

This code gets detailed information about a particular game from an online database using an API Get request. The question I have doesn't pertain to the request but is more about the code itself. The code works. I just think it is long for what needs to be done though. I was wondering if this code is able to be refactored because there are a few places the code just looks the same. I have been trying for last couple of days to get this done with no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

```
def self.get_game_details(game_selection)
    if Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].description == nil
        response = RestClient.get("#{DETAIL_URL}#{Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].slug}", headers = {"x-rapidapi-host" => ENV["HOST"], "x-rapidapi-key" => ENV["API_KEY"]})
        data = JSON.parse(response.body)

        Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].description = data["description"]
        Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].released = data["released"]
        Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].metacritic_rating = data["metacritic"] unless data["metacritic"] == nil # default to 0 if no data

        data["ratings"].each do |rating|
            case rating["title"]
            when "recommended"
                Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].recommended_rating = rating["percent"] unless rating["percent"] == nil # # default to 0.0 if no data
            when "exceptional"
                Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].exceptional_rating = rating["percent"] unless rating["percent"] == nil # # default to 0.0 if no data
            when "meh"
                Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].meh_rating = rating["percent"] unless rating["percent"] == nil # # default to 0.0 if no data
            when "skip"
                Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1].skip_rating = rating["percent"] unless rating["percent"] == nil # # default to 0.0 if no data
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As there is already an answer which is a good starting point, I just wanted to point out some flaws in your code which might help to improve it.

### Use instances instead of class methods

I assume you want to do something like this `Game.get_game_details` which makes sense. However, maybe you should wrap the code in the class method in an instance to leverage local state and make it more readable. Here is an example:

```rb
def self.get_game_details(game_selection)
  Game.new(RemoteGame.new(game_selection.to_i - 1).to_h)
end

class RemoteGame
  HEADERS = { "x-rapidapi-host" => ENV["HOST"], "x-rapidapi-key" => ENV["API_KEY"]
}.freeze

  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end

  def to_h
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end

  private

    attr_reader :id

    def response
     RestClient.get("#{DETAIL_URL}#{game.slug}", headers)
    end

    def game
      @_game ||= Game.all[id].slug
    end
end
```

### Naming

Disclaimer: These are just assumptions!

If the `get_game_details` is on `Game` you should consider remove `game_details` as it's already implicit in the class name. Better might be `Game.find`.

The method parameter `game_selection` looks more like an `id` or `slug`, you should consider renaming it to reflect the name.

### Data structure to store local Games

You always need to subtract `-1` from the `id` so it seems like your local data structure has a different index than your remote data structure. Consider bringing them in sync. One assumption is that you use an array locally which is 0 indexed. 
Maybe you should use a key / value store instead (Hash).

```rb
class Game
  @local_repository = {}

  class << self
    attr_accessor :local_repository

    def all
      local_repository
    end

    def find(id)
      local_repository[id]
    end
  end
end

game = Game.new(id: 1, name: "Name")
Game.all[game.id] = game
Game.find(1)
```

## Rating associations

As your remote data structure already indicates, a `Game` has many `Ratings`. You should reflect that with a composition in your architecture.

```rb
class Rating
  attr_reader :name, :percentage

  def initialize(name, percentage)
    @name = name
    @percentage = percentage
  end
end

class Game
  def ratings
    @_ratings ||= []
  end
end

game = Game.new
game.ratings << Rating.new("Recommended", 50)
```

Another indicator that a class is missing here is that you have the same pre / suffix for several methods:

- recommended_rating
- exceptional_rating
- meh_rating
- skip_rating

These methods all have the `_rating` suffix so we should extract a `Rating` class. This also gives us the flexibility to add another rating in the future very easily. Instead of adding another method to `Game`, we only need to create a new instance of `Rating` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

Answer (score -1):

My approach to your code:

```
# If this data isn't going to change, using constants would be good enough
HEADERS = { 'x-rapidapi-host' => ENV['HOST'],
            'x-rapidapi-key' => ENV['API_KEY'] }.freeze

def self.get_game_details(game_selection)
  # If Game is an ActiveRecord class, probably you should modify this to look
  # for the specific record instead of loading everything with .all
  # If is just a PORO, forget what I said.
  game = Game.all[game_selection.to_i - 1]
  return if game.description.present?

  response = RestClient.get("#{DETAIL_URL}#{slug}", HEADERS)
  data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  game.details = data
end

class Game
  ALLOWED_RATINGS = %w[recommended exceptional meh skip].freeze

  # Moved most of the assigning logic into the Game class. This is debatible as
  # I could use a Service class or another pattern for this, but as I don't
  # know your code's nature, to me looks like the quickest way.
  def details=(data)
    self.description = data['description']
    self.released = data['released']
    # .presence will return nil for blank strings, empty arrays, etc, then with
    # || you will default the value to 0, as:
    #
    #   nil || 0 # => 0
    self.metacritic_rating = data['metacritic'].presence || 0

    data['ratings'].each { |rating| self.rating = rating }
  end

  def rating=(rating)
    # .send method can run any method of this class, so better to check if the
    # value is valid first
    return unless ALLOWED_RATINGS.include? rating['title']

    send("#{rating['title']}_rating=", rating['percent'].presence || 0.0)
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. While this might be a good answer on stackoverflow, it is not a good answer on Code Review. A good answer on Code Review contains at least one insightful observation about the code. Alternate code only solutions are considered poor answers and may be down voted or deleted by the community. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @pacmaninbw hey, thanks for the welcome despite I've been here for more than two years. And yes, I agree with you this isn't the type of expected answers, to my defense, this is an old answer I did when I started in this community and didn't know about what was considered a good answer. Thanks for the heads up though

Comment: I'm going through all the unanswered questions looking for ones with answers that can be up voted. I trying to get our answered questions ratio back over 90%